# How do I understand the set of valid inputs to a Haskell type constructor?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Warning: very beginner question.

I'm currently mired in the section on algebraic types in the Haskell book I'm reading, and I've come across the following example:

```
data Id a =
  MkId a deriving (Eq, Show)

idInt :: Id Integer
idInt = MkId 10

idIdentity :: Id (a -> a)
idIdentity = MkId $ \x -> x
```

OK, hold on. I don't fully understand the `idIdentity` example. The explanation in the book is that:

> This is a little odd. The type `Id` takes an argument and the data
>   constructor `MkId` takes an argument of the corresponding polymorphic
>   type. So, in order to have a value of type `Id Integer`, we need to
>   apply `a -> Id a` to an `Integer` value. This binds the `a` type variable to
>   `Integer` and applies away the `(->)` in the type constructor, giving us
>   `Id Integer`. We can also construct a `MkId` value that is an identity
>   function by binding the `a` to a polymorphic function in both the type
>   and the term level.

But wait. Why only fully polymorphic functions? My previous understanding was that `a` can be **any** type. But apparently constrained polymorphic type doesn't work: `(Num a) => a -> a` won't work here, and the GHC error suggests that only completely polymorphic types or "qualified types" (not sure what those are) are valid:

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> a
f = undefined

idConsPoly :: Id (Num a) => a -> a
idConsPoly = MkId undefined

Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: Num a => a -> a
Perhaps you intended to use ImpredicativeTypes
In the type signature for ‘idIdentity’:
  idIdentity :: Id (Num a => a -> a)
```

**EDIT**: I'm a bonehead. I wrote the type signature below incorrectly, as pointed out by @chepner in his answer below. This also resolves my confusion in the next sentence below...

In retrospect, this behavior makes sense because I haven't defined a `Num` instance for `Id`. But then what explains me being able to apply a type like `Integer` in `idInt :: Id Integer`?

So in generality, I guess my question is: **What specifically is the set of valid inputs to type constructors?** Only fully polymorphic types? What are "qualified types" then? Etc...

Comment: Qualified types are those that have a context, that is, start with `Constraint => ...`. The constraint is the "qualification".

Comment: A good starter to get into qualified types and polymorphism  is this blog article about rank n types https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-18-rank-n-types.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have the type constructor in the wrong place. The following is fine:

```
idConsPoly :: Num a => Id (a -> a)
idConsPoly = MkId undefined
```

---

The type constructor `Id` here has kind `* -> *`, which means you can give it any value that has kind `*` (which includes all "ordinary" types) and returns a new value of kind `*`. In general, you are more concerned with arrow-kinded functions(?), of which type constructors are just one example.

`TypeProd` is a ternary type constructor whose first two arguments have kind `* -> *`:

```
-- Based on :*: from Control.Compose
newtype TypeProd f g a = Prod { unProd :: (f a, g a) }
```

`Either Int` is an expression whose value has kind `* -> *` but is not a type constructor, being the partial application of the type constructor `Either` to the nullary type constructor `Int`.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh. That was a dumb mistake. My apologies. Thank you. So essentially the domain of the type constructor is the set of all possible types, then?

Comment: More or less. There are some subtleties with kinds which I am sure I don't fully understand, but https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind defines ordinary types as having kind `*` and type constructors as having kind `P -> Q` where `P` and `Q` are kinds. (The extra generality there allows `(->)` to have kind `* -> * -> *`, where `P` and `Q` are `*` and `*->*`, respectively.)

Comment: @chepner Minor terminology correction: "type constructor" is a technical term that is orthogonal to the property of having a kind of the form `P -> Q`. For example, `Int` is a type constructor of kind `*`, and `Either Int` has an arrow kind but is not a type constructor. By analogy to term constructors: `False` is a constructor that does not have an arrow type, whereas `(+) 0` has an arrow in its type but is not a constructor.

Comment: I don't think I see why `Either Int` is not a type constructor, since it takes an argument and returns a type, but perhaps this is not the place for that question.

Comment: @chepner, just because that's not what "type constructor" means.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor#Type_constructor describes `Tree` as a unary type constructor defined by `data Tree a = Tip | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)` The only difference I can see between `Tree` and `Either Int` is that the former is a single name and the latter is an expression.

Comment: @chepner, bingo! :)

Comment: @chepner: Interesting... can you summarize this comment discussion into your answer? Then I'll accept. I think it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

Also contributing to your confusion is that you've misinterpreted the error message from GHC. It means "`Num a => a -> a` is a polymorphic or qualified type, and therefore illegal (in this context)".

The last sentence that you quoted from the book is not very well worded, and maybe contributed to that misunderstanding. It's important to realize that in `Id (a -> a)` the argument `a -> a` is *not* a polymorphic type, but just an ordinary type that happens to mention a type variable. The thing which is polymorphic is `idIdentity`, which can have the type `Id (a -> a)` for any type `a`.

In standard Haskell polymorphism and qualification can only appear at the outermost level of the type in a type signature.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm beginning to understand, I think. Do you happen to know of another source I can take a look at to get a better understanding of your explanation in the 2nd paragraph? I'd really like to get a good handle on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The type signature is almost correct

```
idConsPoly :: (Num a) => Id (a -> a)
```

Should be right, though i have no ghc on my phone to test this.

<sub>Also i think your question is quite broad, thus i deliberately answer only the concrete problem here.</sub>